# How to express in numpy the sum of 1 row vector and 1 column vector (octave)

Tags: matlab, numpy, octave

The octave syntax allows to 'add' line vector and column vector to produce matrix:

```
 3 * [1:4] + 4 * [1:4]'
```

This code builds the following matrix :

```
    7   10   13   16
   11   14   17   20
   15   18   21   24
   19   22   25   28
```

Is there any similar way with numpy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use broadcasting:

```
3*np.arange(1,5) + 4*np.arange(1,5)[:,None]
```

Another way would be:

```
np.add.outer(4*np.arange(1,5), 3*np.arange(1,5))
```

resulting output is:

```
 7   10   13   16
11   14   17   20
15   18   21   24
19   22   25   28
```